# Exception in executing COMMAND: Route

Tags: c#

tengo un problema con una aplicacion, cuando quiero hacer un deploy me sale el siguiente error "Exception in executing COMMAND: (ruta)" error 5001. Alguno tiene idea de porque?.

[5001] - Exception in executing COMMAND:'Siemens.SimaticIT.Unified.Engineering.BuildSolutionPackage'

Comment: Deploy a donde?, utilizando que herramienta? Una simple búsqueda del mensaje de error podría darte con la respuesta

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Desconocemos esta libreria que estas utilizando "Siemens.SimaticIT..." pero si estas haciendo un deploy, seguramente y generalmente tienes que tambien llevar la libreria o instalar el componente en destino (seguramente tu para desarrollar tuviste que instalar algo no?  o como utilizasas "Siemens.SimaticIT..."?). Por lo poco que pude "investigar" parece que utilizas "SIMATIC Automation Tool Software Development Kit (SDK)" ¿es asi no? y en el mismo SDK te deberia indicar como se realiza el deploy (temas de licencias, etc) por eso seria bueno que "completes" tu pregunta como te comentan